# Is this quantification correct?

Tags: logic

Let $Q(x,y)$  be the statement $y = 2x +1$ what are the values of the following. The universe is $Z^+$ {1,2,3,....}.

(a) $\forall x\exists y Q(x,y)$ This is true

(b) $\exists x \forall y Q(x,y)$ This is false.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is true.  You are correct.  For the second, truth would imply that 2x+1=1 has a positive integer as a solution, which is false, so you are correct again.

Comment: It's worse than that for the second one, it would imply that for some $x\in\mathbf Z^+$ it holds that $2x-y = 1 = 2x-y'$ for all $y,y'\in\mathbf Z^+$, so it would imply that $y=y'$, thus $|\mathbf Z^+|=1$.